# Сетевое окружение

Tags: сеть

Привет всем!Помогите с проблемой, есть два компа в сети когда они подключены через роутер то с ПК1 можно зайти на сетевую папку \\share другого ПК, а если подключить через хаб без роутера то не получается пишет "Не найден сетевой путь".

Что не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Роутер раздает адреса компьютерам посредством встроенного сервера DHCP, как только вы меняете его на хаб, адреса раздавать некому и компы адреса не получают. Пробейте адреса вручную на каждом компьютере, читай на сетевом адаптере (например, 1ПК-192.168.1.2, 2ПК-192.168.1.3)

Comment: Адреса прописываю 192.168.0.3 и 192.168.0.100 компы пингуются но в сети не видят друг друга

Comment: операционная система? если винда, то проверьте имя рабочей группы... что выставлено в настройках сетевых интерфейсов в качестве DNS-сервера?

Comment: Два компа один на XP второй на Win CE, в настройка сетевых интерфейсов только ip и маска, 192.168.0.3 и 192.168.0.100 маска у обоих 255.255.255.0, соединены хабом.

Comment: Шара где? На ХР? Попробуйте войти в расшаренную папку по сетевому пути (\\192.168.0.*\share). Удачен ли вход?

Comment: Все заработало, прописал айпишники, поменял сетевые имена и все работает ...